# GUI.Button inside GUI.Window not responding

Tags: unity, gui

I am trying to do some GUI work with unity but am having some issues.

I call a window with this code:

```
fortuneRect = GUI.Window(0, fortuneRect, fortuneWindow, "Your future");
```

and inside the window I have a button

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 150, 20), "save fortune")){
       Debug.Log("save fortune button press");
       writeToFile("Button pressed!", "fortune.txt");
       Debug.Log("After save fortune button press");
    }
```

but the button doesn't fire any of its events on click. I tried commenting out the writeToFile but even with only Debugs in the body it doesn't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the button code inside

```
void OnGUI() {...}
```

Provided you ignore the window part, looks fine to me: in other words, the button code on its own, without using a window, should work. Once you have the button code working, go from there. Try doing exactly the same in a brand new project, if all else fails. You should find that alone works, and something else in your current project is preventing proper compilation or runtime operation.

Comment: the button code is inside fortuneWindow(int windowID) which is called from OnGUI()

Comment: Did you try with a fresh project and minimal code? Minimal working test case is the best way to get things operational.

Comment: Apparently GUI.DragWindow stops execution.

Comment: @Iathomas64 Did you solve the issue following this? If my answer led you to some higher understanding, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

your sample looks like the code in Unity's docs
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.Window.html so at first glance should be fine.  Can you provide more info?

The first arg in your call to `GUI.Window()` should be the window id.  Do you mean for that to be zero?  Also, I assume your `GUI.Button(`) call is inside the 'fortuneWindow' callback function.  What does the rest of that function look like?  You're not inside an  `if (windowId != 0)` block or `#ifdef UNITY_EDITOR` or anything?  Do you have overlapping windows that might be stealing each other's focus?

What's your runtime environment?  Is it a custom editor window or a game UI?  Are you seeing this behavior when running in the editor or one of your build targets?

Comment: I can provide more detail tonight when I'm back at home but for now. Yes I mean for that to be 0, its the only window I'm using although I tried changing the value with no success.

My fortuneWindow method doesn't reference the windowID at all

the GUI.Button() call isn't inside any control structures at all. I took these out but I tried putting debug statements before and after the button if block and both fired, its just the insides of the IF that never fired.